# ASP.NET web application namespace not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have created an ASP.NET Web Application, Web Form.

I have added EntityFramework 6.2

I have mapped the DB using **Code First From Existing Database**

Everything went fine, I have all the classes with the context like below:

```
namespace MyProject.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class MyDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyDBEntities ()
            : base("name=MyDBEntities ")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Adm0> Adm0 { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Adm1> Adm1 { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Adm2> Adm2 { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        ...
```

The connection string is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBEntities" connectionString="data source=10.11.xx.xx;initial catalog=xxxxxx;persist security info=True;user id=xxxx;password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

No error in the whole project, but if I try to access the DbContext there is no way!
The namespace DataModel doesn't exist anywhere, is completely ignored:

Example:

Typing *MyProject.* Intellisense doesn't suggest DataModel

Typing *MyProject.DataModel* it gives error on DataModel saying that doesn't exist.

Why??

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to access the context?

Comment: When you try to use the scaffolding command to create a new controller with views and stuff, it asks to specify the context class... is the context available there?

Comment: @sam I've tried to add an API controller, it doesn't ask for anything, just created and inserted it in the MyProject namespace as all the other existing files

Comment: @JonathonChase even if I type using MyProject.... the DataModel namespace is not listed.

Comment: That might be the problem.. you cannot access the namespace.. myproject.datamodel.. So you can't even call any of the model classes from the controller? For ex: initialize like var countries = New Countries();

Comment: What version of the framework are you targetting?

Comment: @JonathonChase latest 4.7.2

Comment: Found the issue...: All the classes created by the ADO.NET Wizard has set their Build Action to CONTENT!! instead of compile. CHanging to compile it works and I can access the namespace. Now the question is WHY has been set to Content, and HOW I can generate them with this property set to compile. (Almost 60 classes and I don't want to change them manaully)

Comment: Edit the .csproj file and  check if this is there:
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Also try to select multiple files using Shift+click and set the build action.

Comment: Did you find an answer? If i answered your question, can i create an answer and you mark that as the accepted answer? @Giox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you more than a project in your solution?
If so, you should add a reference between the project where you want to use your DbContext and the project that contains it.

From the official documentation:

> To add a reference, right click on the References or Dependencies node in Solution Explorer and choose Add Reference
>   [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019)

Also, make sure that the project that contains the DbContext is being compiled.

Comment: no, only one project in the solution, and it contains only the data model, no other code for now, no other libraries, just created right now.